# Enable gzip compression in CXF client

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm trying to make my client use gzip.  I have the GZip Feature enabled in the server.  It seems that the client it's not sending the correct header:

```
POST /api/v1/data HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.6.2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: localhost:8001
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 539
```

Here's the code where I create the client:

```
 private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName(
            "http://xxx/", "IData");
    private static final QName PORT_NAME = new QName(
            "http://xxx/", "IDataPort");
    IData port;

    public void initPort() {
        Service service = Service.create(SERVICE_NAME);
        // Endpoint Address
        String endpointAddress = ClientUtil.getUrl()
                + "data";

        // Add a port to the Service
        service.addPort(PORT_NAME, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING,
                endpointAddress);

        port = service.getPort(IData.class);
    }
```

The IData interface implements has the GZip Annotation:

```
@WebService
@GZIP
public interface IData ....
```

Comment: does the header come from some network analyzer, like tcpmon?

Comment: I'm using Grinder to proxy the connection and get a dump of the traffic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solution:

After a revision, this is what you need:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
client.getInInterceptors().add(new GZIPInInterceptor());
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new GZIPOutInterceptor());
```

After that it worked.

Comment: And for JAX-RS RESTful clients:  
`Client client = WebClient.client(port);  
ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(client);  
config.getInInterceptors().add(new GZIPInInterceptor());  
config.getOutInterceptors().add(new GZIPOutInterceptor());`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4/cxf_jaxws/JavaFirst-AnnotateCxf-Compress.html

> "GZIP is a negotiated enhancement. That is, an initial request from a
>   client will not be gzipped, but an Accept header will be added and, if
>   the server supports GZIP compression, the response will be gzipped and
>   any subsequent requests will be also."

Check if the web service accepts Gzip, and check only requests after the first request.

Comment: What I need was to configure the client that it will send the header to trigger the negotiation that you mention. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When only gzip'in the response from the server and not the the request from the client, then you need to add the header and the `GZIPInInterceptor` like to following:

```
// add accept-encoding header
Map<String, Object> requestHeaders = new HashMap<>();
requestHeaders.put("Accept-Encoding", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("gzip")));
((BindingProvider)service).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, requestHeaders);

// encode response from server
client.getInInterceptors().add(new GZIPInInterceptor());
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to enable gzip:

```
List<Feature> features = Arrays.asList(new GZIPFeature())
final WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(uri, null, features, null);
```

GZipFeature will automatically add "in interceptor", "out interceptor" and "out fault interceptor".

Answer (score 0):

more detailed answer to above mentioned answer

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);

//this line to send compressed(gzip) request to server
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new GZIPOutInterceptor());

//this in to uncompress server response at client side
client.getInInterceptors().add(new GZIPInInterceptor());
```

Comment: why it is down voted..? provided more clarification..?