# CXF JAX-RS 2.0 client, difficulty adding compression and/or logging interceptors

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I am trying to use the JAX-RS 2.0 client in CSF 3.x, but am having some difficulty finding a way to programatically add interceptors to the client. I'n particular I'm trying to add the regular gzip and logging interceptors, something that worked well on the server side, to the client side as well.

I would prefer to use the JAX-RS standard client, rather than the CXF-specific WebClient or Proxy methods. I'm not opposed to some CXF-specific code in configuring the client, or using a different API than can then be converted to a JAX-RS standard Client/WebTarget, but to tie the entire client to CXF is undesirable to me.

I can accomplish what I intend to do by implementing my own Client(Request|Response)Filters, but it would be preferable to reused the well-tested logic that CXF already contains for this purpose.

This all seems rather simple to do if I was using Jersey, but does anyone have any idea on how to do this in CXF?

Comment: please check this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/12523750/1129313

Comment: Unfortunately that example does not produce a JAX-RS 2.0 client, but a CXF WebClient which requires all requests to be written to a CXF-specific API.